# Can anyone tell me what this flower is called I’m in Surrey UK

Tags: identification, flowers

My 5 year old granddaughter asked me what this flower was called and I have no clue.

[image: jasmine in flower]

Answer (score 5):

It is *Jasminum officinale*, a very vigorous climbing, twining, hardy plant commonly known as Jasmine. It is deciduous, and those flowers should be fragrant, especially noticeable mid afternoon/evening on a warm or hot day.  https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/9454/jasminum-officinale/details